# failed to decode and parse json on Xcode projet

Tags: swift, xcode

The message is not clear enough to understand which one to fix

- the JSON file seems to have the correct format
- is it the model on the SwiftUI View that I need to correct ?

this is my json file :

```
[
    {
        "name": "Paris",
        "image":"charleyrivers",
        "lat": 48.85877,
        "lng": 2.2069488,
        "description": "Most beautiful city in the world"
    },
    {
        "name": "London",
        "image":"chilkoottrail",
        "lat": 51.528308,
        "lng": -0.3817893,
        "description": "Most beautiful city in the world"
    }
]
```

this is the model :

```
import SwiftUI

struct City: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var image: String
    var lat: String
    var lng: String
    var description: String
}
```

this is the helper function to decode every JSON object

```
//
//  Helper.swift
//  A small collection of quick helpers to avoid repeating the same old code.
//
//  Created by Paul Hudson on 23/06/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 Hacking with Swift. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

extension Bundle {
    func decode<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from file: String) -> T {
        guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
            fatalError("Failed to locate \(file) in bundle.")
        }

        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
            fatalError("Failed to load \(file) from bundle.")
        }

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        guard let loaded = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle.")
        }

        return loaded
    }
}
```

Finally, the swiftUI View where I am attempting to read the JSON file

```
[![import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let cities = Bundle.main.decode(\[City\].self, from: "cities.json")
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
        
        NavigationView {
            List {
              
                ForEach(cities) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        ItemDetail(item: item)
                    } label: {
                        ItemRow(item: item)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Cities")
    
            .listStyle(.grouped)
        }
    
    }
}][1]][1]
```

Comment: Change `try?` to a `do try catch` you will get a better error

Comment: for a start, lat and lng aren't strings in the JSON...

Comment: @flanker is correct. Also, `City` has an id property but the JSON is missing the corresponding id.